# With such a low mass, how do enzymes use quantum tunneling to lower the activation energy in a reaction

Tags: quantum-tunneling

The Sun uses quantum tunneling to create nuclear fusion, but only can achieve this through it's large mass. So how can enzymes in our body achieve this feat?

Comment: Quantum tunneling has very little to do with mass.

Comment: yes it does; the more volume and mass in a object, the more likely quantum tunneling will occur.

Comment: The likelihood of quantum tunneling depends only on the height of a particular energy barrier, the energy of the tunneling particle, and the frequency of collisions with the energy barrier (i.e. the degree of confinement). The Sun creates a high degree of confinement with gravitation, but that's the only way that mass comes into it. We don't need a lot of mass to create fusion on earth - all we need is high magnetic fields.